# Python: Finding combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list, to make it easier to understand it's structure I'll write it out like so:

```
mylist = [[["a","b","c","d"]...]...]
```

Where the `...` means the previous list is repeated (although the values inside may change)

An example list would be:

```
mylist = [[["a","b","c","d"], ["e","f","g","h"]], [["i", "j", "k", "l"]], [["m","n","o","p"], ["q","r","s","t"]]]
```

My current method is:

```
mylist2 = []
for a in mylist[0]:
    for b in mylist[1]:
        for c in mylist[2]:
            mylist2.append([a,b,c])
```

However this is very long, especially since in my actual code it goes on up to `for x in mylist[35]`

Is there a better way for me to write this code?

Comment: `.. this is very long..` - did you mean it takes a long time to execute?  Will you be using `mylist2` more than once?

Comment: @wwii I mean the code is very long. There are nested for loops in for loops in for loops... Around 35 times. That's 35 tabs before code! Surely there's a shorter and faster way to do this

Comment: And the variable `mylist2` is returned from the function as soon as it is found

Comment: Did you look through the Python docs for something that might work for you?

Comment: @wwii I can't find anything. Do you have something in mind?

Comment: Something in https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code

```
%%timeit
mylist2 = []
for a in mylist[0]:
    for b in mylist[1]:
        for c in mylist[2]:
            mylist2.append([a,b,c])
# 809 ns ± 18.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

use `itertools`

```
import itertools
%%timeit
list(itertools.product(*mylist))
# 528 ns ± 11.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Minor difference in behavior: The latter makes a `list` of three-`tuple`s, where the former is making three-`list`s. If mutability is required, the latter can be efficiently made to match the former by `map`ping to `list`: `list(map(list, itertools.product(*mylist)))`. But yes, this is the obvious way to go here, and especially useful when `mylist` might have a variable number of sub-`list`s.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you for your suggestion.